# how to check if querying the cmis repository returns empty

Tags: cmis

```
    queryString = " ..." ;
    ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query(queryString, false);
    // this line simply fails, it doesn't throw an exception.
    for (QueryResult qResult : results) {
       // ....
    }
```

Is there any way to check if **results** is empty before starting the for-loop ?

thanks

Comment: looks like there is no other way than to try and catch any Exception that may happen.

Answer (score 0):

The session.query() method does not contact the repository. It only prepares an object ('results') that can talk to the repository and perform the query. As long as you haven't pulled from this 'results' object, it doesn't know anything about the result set. In your example, the for-loop pulls for the first time. If the result set is empty, the loop is skipped.

If you don't like to use the loop to check if there are results, you can do this before the loop:

```
if (results.getPageNumItems() == 0) {
  // break here
}
```

The getPageNumItems() method fetches the first batch (page) of query results. If the result set is empty, this first batch is empty. Performance-wise it doesn't matter if you do this or checking if the loop has been skipped. Both are doing the same round-trip to the server.

It should not throw an exception, throw. If it does, check your query and - depending on the exception - talk to your repository vendor.